# multiple overflow:hidden containers with hidden content simultaneously toggled by links

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page I have one **navigation menu** and **two** content containers.

The content containers use **overflow:hidden** so that only **one** of the child div's show at one time.

What I would like is for the navigation links to act as activators for the related content to scroll in to view in the containers.

So, for example if I was to press **Link2** on the navigation I would like div **anchor2** in **First Content Box** and **anchor2** in **Second Content Box** to scroll in to view.

See example code below:

### Navigation

```
  <div id="navigation">
  <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor1">Link1</a></div>
  <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor2">Link2</a></div>
  <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor3">Link3</a></div>
  <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor4">Link4</a></div>
  </div>
```

### First Content Box

```
  <div id="page_identifier_box">
  <div class="anchor1"></div>
  <div class="anchor2"></div>
  <div class="anchor3"></div>
  <div class="anchor4"></div>
  </div>
```

### Second Content Box

```
  <div id="page_information_box">
  <div class="anchor1"></div>
  <div class="anchor2"></div>
  <div class="anchor3"></div>
  <div class="anchor4"></div>
  </div>
```

### My conclusions

1. If I was only controlling one content box via the navigation I would use unique anchors. This method does not work with my dilemma though as you can only point to one anchor in a link and even if I was to put the same name anchor in both containers the browser would only initiate the first container anchor and then give up.
2. My idea is to use some sort of jquery script or php script to tell all containers to scroll to specific div class (for example div class anchor3). This is a theory but I have no clue how this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **zgood's solution** I have managed to adapt to take in to account the possibility of different variations on container widths. Here is my solution in case anybody else was looking for it.

**CSS Code**

In this part we separate the page_indentifier_box and page_information box and give each it's own unique inner (& secondinner) and slide (&secondslide) properties.

```
#page_identifier_box{
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
width:100px;
}

.slide{
width:100px;
float:left;
}

.inner{
width:400px;
}

#page_information_box{
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
width:200px;
}

.secondslide{
width:200px;
float:left;
}

.secondinner{
width:800px;
}
```

**JQuery Code**

In this part we create a new var, in this case "var g" to control the second container.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav_link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var s = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var m = "0px";
    switch (s) {
        case 'anchor2':
            m = "-100px";
            break;
        case 'anchor3':
            m = "-200px";
            break;
        case 'anchor4':
            m = "-300px";
            break;
    }
    var g = "0px";
    switch (s) {
        case 'anchor2':
            g = "-200px";
            break;
        case 'anchor3':
            g = "-400px";
            break;
        case 'anchor4':
            g = "-600px";
            break;
    }
    $('.inner').animate({ marginLeft: m }, 750);
    $('.secondinner').animate({ marginLeft: g }, 750);
});
});
```

**HTML Code**

again here we adapt the html for the second container to allow for the use of the above new values for the second container.

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor1">Link1</a></div>
<div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor2">Link2</a></div>
<div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor3">Link3</a></div>
<div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor4">Link4</a></div>
</div>

<div id="page_identifier_box">
   <div class="inner">
      <div class="anchor1 slide">anchor1</div>
      <div class="anchor2 slide">anchor2</div>
      <div class="anchor3 slide">anchor3</div>
      <div class="anchor4 slide">anchor4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page_information_box">
  <div class="secondinner">
      <div class="anchor1 secondslide">anchor1</div>
      <div class="anchor2 secondslide">anchor2</div>
      <div class="anchor3 secondslide">anchor3</div>
      <div class="anchor4 secondslide">anchor4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Summary**

Hope this all makes sense. A big thanks to **zgood** for his help and all others that replied with an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that since you lament the inability to use ID's the problem of scrolling something is not the main topic. It sounds like you mostly care about how to obtain a reference the corresponding entities. JQuery uses CSS style selectors, so you should be able to do `"$(#page_informtion_box .anchor1")` to select (and then scroll to) the info box and `"$("#page_identifer_box .anchor1")` to select (and scroll to) the identifer div.

You can build the jquery selector for each based on what menu item was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your CSS is but you can try this...
CSS:

```
    #page_identifier_box{
        overflow:hidden;
        float:left;
        width:100px;
    }
     #page_information_box{
        overflow:hidden;
        float:left;
        width:200px;
     }
    .slide{
        width:100px;
        float:left;
    }
    .slide2{
        width:200px;
        float:left;
    }
    .inner{
        width:400px;
    }
    .inner2{
        width:800px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="navigation">
      <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor1">Link1</a></div>
      <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor2">Link2</a></div>
      <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor3">Link3</a></div>
      <div class="nav_link"><a href="anchor4">Link4</a></div>
    </div>

        <div id="page_identifier_box">
           <div class="inner">
              <div class="anchor1 slide">anchor1</div>
              <div class="anchor2 slide">anchor2</div>
              <div class="anchor3 slide">anchor3</div>
              <div class="anchor4 slide">anchor4</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="page_information_box">
  <div class="inner2">
      <div class="anchor1 slide2">anchor1</div>
      <div class="anchor2 slide2">anchor2</div>
      <div class="anchor3 slide2">anchor3</div>
      <div class="anchor4 slide2">anchor4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav_link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var m = 0;
        switch (s) {
            case 'anchor2':
                m = -100;
                break;
            case 'anchor3':
                m = -200;
                break;
            case 'anchor4':
                m = -300;
                break;
        }
        $('.inner').animate({ marginLeft: m + 'px' }, 850);
        $('.inner2').animate({ marginLeft: (m*2) + 'px' }, 750);
    });
});
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is so close! The function is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The only problem is that by defining the anchor scroll distance ( case 'anchor2': m = "-100px"; ) that must limit the containers to be the same width. How could I achieve the effect if say one container was 100px wide but the other was 200px wide..

Comment: I edited it. Try the new code and see if it works.  You may have to play with the animation speeds since the divs are different sizes.  If the containing div isn't exactly twice as big as the other div container you could always create another variable like "var m2" and use that in your switch statement and use "m2" in the animate instead of "(m*2)".

Comment: ah I just figured it out another way (as now posted above) above but yours is maybe cleaner. thanks a lot!